# How can these dart functions be changed to work with null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm new to coding and having trouble figuring out how to fix the errors having to do with adaptation to null safety.

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=4bf7549c820d1adb4be8673e92820e43

```
void main() {
  
 int step1Result = add(n1: 5, n2: 9);
  
 int step2Result = multiply(step1Result, 5);
  
 double finalResult = step2Result / 3;
  
 print(finalResult);
  
}



int add({int n1, int n2}) {
  
  return = n1 + n2;
  
}

int multiply(int n1, int n2) {
  
  return = n1 * n2;
  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

named constructor parameters are optional. You need to make them required or nullable.

```dart
int add({required int n1, required int n2}) {
  return n1 + n2;
}

int multiply(int n1, int n2) {
  return n1 * n2;
}
```

And nullable case, I am providing default value as 0

```dart
int add({int? n1, int? n2}) {
  return n1 ?? 0 + (n2 ?? 0);
}
```

You can explore more [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) And   [using-constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)